# Change background of button via classname

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a button whose background color i wanna change on a certain condition. When I use the ID it works, but not when i use the classname. Any ideas?

Button:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-default" id="reset" onclick="reset();" style="width:150px; background-color:black; color:white;">Zurücksetzen</a>
```

Code:

```
... if(com == true && (IDs.length >= correctOrder.length))
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById('messagewindow')
        .innerHTML = 'Done!';
    }else
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('messagewindow')
        .innerHTML = 'Try again!';
    }
```

Comment: a quick guess; If you use the ID, you get the actual object, where you can apply a CSS Rule, but if you use the class, it returns a collection, since a class can appear multiple times (an ID should only appear once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` return a node collection so if you have just one element targeted by that class name you need to access the first element

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-default')[0]
```

in this case you could also use `querySelector()`

```
document.querySelector('.btn-default')
```

Comment: thank you so much! works like a charm!